# Poor performance of Spring Controller returning blob

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Application with Spring Web MVC, Spring Security and Spring Data JPA at Version 2.2.0. I experience really bad performance on a public controller that returns a byte-Array. It takes 150-350ms to transfer a 1.5MB blob. An identical controller in an "empty" Spring Boot Starter project (from start.spring.io) needs <30ms to transfer 1.5MB. I don't know where to start looking for the problem. Any ideas? I measured the time on localhost with the default embedded tomcat server by requesting the file in Chrome.

```
@GetMapping("/blob")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getBlob() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("image/jpeg"))
            .body(new byte[(int) (1024 * 1024 * 1.5)]);
}
```

Comment: Hello have you found any solution for this please ?